# awk to ignore leading and trailing space and blank lines and commented lines if any from a file

Tags: shell, awk

Need help on awk

awk to ignore leading and trailing space and blank lines and commented lines if any from a file

Comment: Step 1: Write a regex that matches what you want.  2) use it. 3) profit!

Comment: That is perhaps not a helpful comment, so let me be more clear.  Your question is extremely vague and demonstrates very little effort on your part.  What exactly are you having trouble with?  Do you know how to match trailing whitespace?  Do you know how to process data with awk?  Do you know how to redirect output to a file?  What have you tried, and how is it failing?

Comment: I'm able to ignore the leading and trailing spaces and commented and blank lines  in a file using separate commands of 'awk'.
awk '$1 ~ /^[^#]/' file1 | sort > output.txt
awk  'gsub(/^[\t]+|[\t]+$/,"") file1

Just want this two commands in one line

Comment: The RS variable may be what you want. And the ‘next’ statement.

Comment: Could you please explain me in detail or with the command? It can be any unix command..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
grep "MyText"  FromMyLog.log |awk -F "      " '{print $2}'|awk -F "#" '{print $1}'
```

Here **MyText** is the key to grep from file **FromMyLog.log**

**-F** is used to avoid the following value, here space between quotes.

**'{print $2}'** will print the 2nd argument from the output, you can use $1, $2 as your requirement.

**awk -F "#"** This will ignore the commented lines.

This is just a hint for you, Modify the code with your requirements. This works for me while grep.

`grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' <filename>` or `egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$|^ *#' <file_name>` (if white spaces)

Comment: Hi Syam,
Thanks for your response. My question is, if a file looks like below

abc

asd
gfs
  uyt
#poi
lkj
==========================
The output that am looking for is like

abc
asd
gfs
uyt
lkj

Comment: Okay,
Try the below.
cat filename| egrep -v "^\s*(#|$)"

egrep -v      means leave the following out
^#.*             means patterns that begin with a #
|                  means or
^$               means patterns that are empty

Comment: Thanks syam.. could you also please update the command with ignoring leading and trailing spaces

Comment: You may try :
egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$|^ *#' <file_name> (if white spaces ) or grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#'   <file_name>  for ease use.
This will work for you.
If works you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were asking for:

```
$> echo -e '   abc   \t
\t efg   
# alskdjfl
 #
awk       

 # askdfh
' | 
awk '
    # match if first none space character is not a hash sign
    /^[[:space:]]*[^#]/ { 
        # delete any spaces from start and end of line
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*/, ""); 
        sub(/[[:space:]]*$/, "", NF);  # `NF` is Number of Fields
        print 
}'
abc
efg
awk
```

This can be folded onto a single line if so needed. Any problems, an actual example of the input (in a code block in your question) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's one way to extract required content ignoring spaces**

**FILE CONTENT**

```
Server:     192.168.XX.XX
Address 1:  192.168.YY.YY
Name:       central.google.com
```

Now to extract the server's address without spaces.

**COMMAND**

```
awk -F':' '/Server/ '{print $2}' YOURFILENAME | tr -s " "
```

option -s for squeezing the repetition of spaces.

which gives,

```
 192.168.XX.XX
```

Here, notice that there is one leading space in the address.

To completely ignore spaces you can change that to,

```
awk -F':' '/Server/ '{print $2}' YOURFILENAME | tr -d [:space:]
```

option -d for removing particular characters, which is [:space:] here.

which gives,

```
192.168.YY.YY
```

without any leading or trailing spaces.

**tr** is an UNIX utility for translating, or deleting, or squeezing repeated characters. **tr** refers to translate here.

**Examples:**

```
tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
```

gives,

```
YOUAREAWESOME
```

for

```
youareawesome
```

Hope that helps.